# Strip Inline CSS and JavaScript in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sanitize

I'm working on a Rails application and I would like to know what's the best way to strip blocks of CSS or JavaScript.

```
<style>
...
</style>
  -or-
<script>
...
</script>
```

I'm using the *strip_tags* helper to take care of most of the HTML, but it leaves a bunch of CSS when the content contains inline CSS. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to use Nokogiri library:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str = " ... " # some html from user
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
doc.css("style,script").remove # remove all tags with content
new_string = doc.to_s
```

Nokogiri can much more, but this is what you asked for in questions :-)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to do this is using the [sanitize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#M001622) method. The strip_tags method is somewhat limited and less secure:

> [strip_tags] Strips all HTML tags from the html,
>   including comments. This uses the
>   html-scanner tokenizer and so its HTML
>   parsing ability is limited by that of
>   html-scanner.

If you use sanitize, you will be much more secure, just come up with a white list of tags you intend to allow first.

Comment: Thanks, but that won't solve my issue. I'd like to get rid of the opening and closing style tags, plus all inline CSS between those tags as well. This way I'm only left with plain text.

Answer (score 0):

If you need user-provided CSS for your application, you can try using http://github.com/courtenay/css_file_sanitize/tree/master as well.

Comment: Thanks, this will definitely be useful, but it doesn't answer my question (see above comment). Thanks